# Crypto private key storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, cryptocurrency

We are building a site where we use cryptocurrency to pay commission, and we have a challenge with saving the private key on our AWS system. No matter how we save it then it can easily be retrieved by developers.

What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at some stage anybody with 'Admin' access can see anything in your AWS Account.

If you are willing for this to happen but want to know when it has happened, you can [Log AWS Secrets Manager events with AWS CloudTrail - AWS Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/monitoring-cloudtrail.html) so you can see when people access the private key.

If, however, you don't want any developers to be able to access the key (but you still want your app to be able to use it), there are a few options...

One option would be *NOT* to store the key. Then, when your application starts up, somebody must supply the key to the program and **the key is kept in memory**. If the program stops running, the key is 'lost' and must be re-entered when it is restarted. You could even give half the key to two different people and they must enter half the key each -- this prevents one person from having the whole key. (They could use a browser-based password manager to store the secret so they don't have to re-type it.)

Another option is to **create a separate AWS Account** and store the key in that account. Don't give developers access to that account -- only give access to two trusted people. Then, when your application needs the key, it can 'call' the second AWS Account (eg via an API call or invoking an AWS Lambda function) and 'request' the key. This should be accompanied with a One-Time Password (OTP) that the trusted people could keep on their phone. If the correct OTP is provided, then the key is returned and again it should be **kept in memory** rather than stored on disk.

It's up to you to determine 'who to trust' and 'how much trust' to give various people.